# Ignition Location does not receive location updates

Tags: android, maven, aspectj

I try using [ignition-location](https://github.com/kaeppler/ignition/tree/master/ignition-location) to get location updates in my Activity. The [sample project](https://github.com/kaeppler/ignition/tree/master/ignition-location/ignition-location-samples) does work. So far I did the following:

1. Added ignition-location apklib dependency to my pom.xml
2. Added Annotations to the class (@IgnitedLocationActivity()) and the Location member variable (@IgnitedLocation)
3. Implemented lifecycle methods: onCreate, onResume, onPause, onStart, onStop, onDestroy
4. Added plugin configurations from sample pom.xml
5. Implemented OnIgnitedLocationChangedListener in my Activity

But the Location is not set automagically. There is no log to show because onIgnitedLocationChanged() is not called.

As I understand it ignition-location works by adding certain setters via aspectj to my Activity in the build process. It seems this is not happening to my Activity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The sample project stopped working when I removed the parent project reference from the sample pom.xml. So I knew it had to do with the poms above the sample project.

I needed to add the following from the parent pom:

```
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
  <artifactId>aspectj-maven-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>1.4</version>
  <configuration>
    <aspectLibraries>
      <aspectLibrary>
        <groupId>com.github.ignition</groupId>
        <artifactId>ignition-location</artifactId>
        <type>apklib</type>
      </aspectLibrary>
    </aspectLibraries>
    <source>1.6</source>
  </configuration>
  <executions>
    <execution>
      <phase>process-sources</phase>
      <goals>
        <goal>compile</goal>
      </goals>
    </execution>
  </executions>
</plugin>
```

The execution was missing in the sample projects [pom.xml](https://github.com/kaeppler/ignition/blob/master/ignition-location/ignition-location-samples/pom.xml).